# compare million records from CSV file with database table in Apache nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a usecase where i want to fetch csv file from sftp . The CSV file will have 6 millions to 10 millions records.Once after the fetch,I want to insert the filename and status as 'Initiated' into the table(file_tracker). I want to compare 2 columns from CSV (MDN and status) with the columns available in database table (mdn_line_status) with 2 columns (MDN and status).

After comparision i have to route the unmatched records into another table (mdn_mismatch_staging) and route those records to kafka, and update status as 'Ready to process' in the table (file_tracker) and stop the process once all the unmatched records  has been sent to kafka.

Also if there is no mismatch records , i want to route into the table (file_tracker)  and update filename and status as 'No mismatch' and stop the process.

I have attached here the nifi template which i am using for this scenario.

List of issues :

**1.The flow is working fine for smaller data, when it comes to larger records, getting issue with MergeRecord processor. I am not able to merge the unmatched records in the whole. Instead merge only process only few records regardless of the min and max values specified.

2.Second notify processor is not working properly, It sends signal to the first wait processor which not related in any manner.

3. I am not able to get the exact count of matched and unmatched records after lookuprecord processor.**

Someone Please help me in resolving these 3 major issues.

since stackoverflow not allowed to attach files, i have attached the link to the template xml.

[enter link description here][1]

Thanks in advance.

```
  [1]: https://pastebin.com/bX9ahtUr
```